# `fwrite` doesn't work directly after `fread`?

Tags: c++, windows, file-io, stdio

I have a program which uses stdio for reading and writing a binary file. It caches the current stream position and will not seek if the read/write offset is already at the desired position.

However, an interesting problem appears, that **when a byte is read and the following byte is written, it doesn't actually get written!**

Here is a program to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("test.bin", "wb");
    unsigned char d[1024] = { 0 };
    fwrite(d, 1, 1024, f);
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("test.bin", "rb+");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        unsigned char a[1] = { 255 - (unsigned char)(i) };
        fflush(f);
        fwrite(a, 1, 1, f);
        fflush(f);
        fseek(f, i, SEEK_SET);
        fread(a, 1, 1, f);
        printf("%02X ", a[0]);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

You are supposed to see it write the bytes `FF` down to `00`, however only the first byte is written because it does not follow a `fread` immediately.

If it seeks before `fwrite`, it acts correctly.

The problem happens on Visual Studio 2010/2012 and TDM-GCC 4.7.1 (Windows), **however it works on [codepad](http://codepad.org/1a3d4xQq)** which I guess is due to it being executed on Linux.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: You know what buffered writing is and `fflush()` is for?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, actually I've tried flushing but it still don't work. I'll update the question

Comment: He dumped it in the lounge six minutes after asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C99 §7.18.5.3/6 (quoted from N869 final draft):

> “When a file is opened with update mode (’+’ as the second or third character in the
>   above list of mode argument values) […] input shall not be directly followed by output without an
>   intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-
>   of-file.”

Comment: Thanks for digging into the spec, this explains everything.